# why do keep getting warnings in this makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

```
CC := cc
NAME := minishell
SRCS = ./Srcs/xsh.c
DIR = .build  
OBJS := $(SRCS:%.c=$(DIR)%.o)
OBJS := $(addprefix $(DIR), $(OBJS))
$(DIR)/%.o : %.c 
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $<
$(NAME) : $(OBJS) | $(DIR)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
$(DIR):
    mkdir -p $(@)
all : $(NAME)
```

I am trying to store all .o files in the build directory

Makefile:12: warning: overriding commands for target .build

Makefile:8: warning: ignoring old commands for target .build

make: *** No rule to make target %.c, needed by .build.  Stop

Comment: You didn't mention what errors/warnings you're getting, which makes it hard for us to help, but the `\` at the end of the `SRCS` line looks suspicious.

Comment: The trailing ``\`` after `SRCS = ...` is extremely sus. Like in C, it lindicates line continuation.

Comment: I removed '\' but nothing changed

Comment: Use `$(info OBJS=[$(OBJS)])` after each assignment to `OBJS`.  I suspect the values are not what you want/expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line numbers are off by one which makes these errors hard to understand.  Please be sure to include the exact makefile and errors so that they match up.

However, I assume that line #8 is:

```
$(DIR)/%.o : %.c
```

and line #12 is:

```
$(DIR):
```

The only way that this could give that error is if your `DIR` variable ended in spaces:

```
DIR = .build  
            ^-space here
```

Makefiles preserve ending spaces on variables so be sure you don't do that.

Note if you had a newer version of GNU make it would warn about this:

```
Makefile:8: *** mixed implicit and normal rules: deprecated syntax
```

I guess that's still not super-helpful but it's something! :)

Comment: Nice! This is why one should configure their editor to strip trailing spaces on save.